# How to access an object's property by key in Typescript

Tags: typescript

How do I access a property on an object type with it's key name in Typescript?

```
type MyType = {
  text: string;
}

var item: MyType = {
  text: "Hello World!"
}

// How do I do this?
let keyName = "text";
let key = keyName;
item[key] = "New Value";
```

I get this error.

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'MyType'.   No index signature
> with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'MyType'.

Comment: If you declare it with `const` you will find that it works. That's because the type is now the literal `"text"` and you can access the property `text`. For arbitrary strings, you either have to check and cast, or use an index signature, but the former is probably preferable for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `key` is generalised as `string` if you don't explicitly specify a type for it:

```js
let key = "text" // let key: string
```

You can constrain values for `key` to only keys of `MyType`, after which it is okay to use it as access key for `item`:

```js
let key: keyof MyType = "text" // let key: string
```

See a [working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQUrAgD2AC4oBnYAJwEsA7AcwG4MBfDDANwENypLcBbYnESQoqTNlwFiAIgASEADYKA9lADqy8goAmAQmnNWCiMCgBrCCGIWQygGawESUVGmTg0xrwh8A2jYBdF2kAOQgAdygANQ4FAFcITyA).

Comment: Thank you! I made one small edit to my example. I have a function returning the string for the key name. I'm still not sure how to resolve that as I still get an error if I try do this. `let keyName = "text";
let key: keyof MyType = keyName;`